# Variance of sum of $m$ dependent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limit-theorems

I originally posted this question in Mathstackexchange, but since I got no answer I'm posting it also here.

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of identically distributed and $m$-dependent random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$, $0<\operatorname{Var}(X_i)<\infty$ ($m$-dependent means that each $X_i$ is independent of $X_{i+j}$ for $|i-j|\ge m $.

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)<\infty$.

Assume also that $Y$ is independent of $X_m,X_{m+1},...$

We know that
$$ \frac{Y+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{n}}\overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2) $$

from the Hoeffding-Robbins theorem, but I am struggling to show that $\sigma^2>0 $ even though intuitively it seems true.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: To start, the appearance of $Y$ doesn't affect anything, because $Y/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ a.s., and Slutsky's lemma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the random variable (r.v.) $Y$ plays no role here, since $Y/\sqrt n\to0$.

Second, $\sigma^2$ may be zero. However, in the abstract of [Janson](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=2ahUKEwjzvpeOs_DgAhUh4IMKHcsUDvUQFjAHegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1312.1563&usg=AOvVaw1ilXV3k-sugaFEmxz4u71y) we find this complete answer to your question:

> It is well-known that the central limit theorem holds for partial sums
>   of a stationary sequence $(X_i)$ of $m$-dependent random variables
>   with finite variance; however, the limit may be degenerate with
>   variance $0$ even if $\text{Var}\,(X_i)\ne0$. We show that this happens only in
>   the case when $X_i − \text{E}\,X_i = Y_i − Y_{i−1}$ for an $(m − 1)$-dependent
>   stationary sequence $(Y_i)$ with finite variance (a result implicit in
>   earlier results)